RN Expo app - EAS preview build won’t load ad mob ads
I have built a react native app with expo and EAS.
My admob account is verified, and I have setup a payment method. I am hoping to use test flight to beta test my app but the ads are an important feature, and I do not want to have to use test ads in beta.
Any help would be much appreciated!p
On both simulator builds and preview builds my app shows admob test ads perfectly for both banner and interstitial reward. However I add logic to check the environment and when not in dev, use the real admob ad ids. On iOS simulator the ads load, but when I run a preview  build on eas and download the new build to my iOS phone the ads do not load.
